# ternary operator usage within IF brackets

Tags: conditions

could you please help me understand this ternary operator

```
public static <E> void replace(List<E> list, E val, E newVal) {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if (val == null ? it.next() == null : val.equals(it.next()))
            it.set(newVal);
}
```

i thought the part after ? is just a regular statement, so how is == being used here?

Comment: `it.next() == null` is an expression, `val.equals(it.next()))` is an expression. If `val == null`, evaluate the former, else evaluate the latter.

Answer (score 3):

It's very easy to see, once you start to pull out the expression into a separate variable:

```
public static <E> void replace(List<E> list, E val, E newVal) {
for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); )
    T theVariable = val == null ? it.next() == null : val.equals(it.next());
    if (theVariable)
        it.set(newVal);
}
```

I intentionally left the type as `T`. When you think about what type it has to be, the answer to your question appears: As the variable is used as the condition of an if-expression, it must be a `boolean` type, and hence, it is clear, what `it.next() == null` is doing here.

You just happened to run into the case where `a ? b : c` has three elements `a,b,c` which are all of type `boolean`.

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal EXPRESSION, which in this case returns a boolean.  It is the equivalent of:

```
public static <E> void replace(List<E> list, E val, E newVal) {
    for (ListIterator<E> it = list.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        bool cond = val == null ? it.next() == null : val.equals(it.next());
        if (cond) {
            it.set(newVal);
        }
     }
}
```

A ternary expression returns a value.